# change registry value for currently logged in Windows user, when running script as SYSTEM user (batch)

Tags: batch-file, scheduled-tasks

I have this code in a batch script.

```
REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\MyKey /ve /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

The problem is the script is run using the system account as a scheduled task in Windows. When using the system account to run the task it does not apply the value to the currently logged in Windows user's registry. I could not find a way to set the task to use the currently logged in user, so had to set it to use the system account.

I attempted to use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18324038/reg-add-for-loop) solution; however it does not apply to the currently logged in user because the NTUSER.DAT file is being used by another process.

I also attempted to import a .reg file; however that also does not apply it to the currently logged in user.

How can I make apply the setting to `HKEY_USERS\*\MyKey`? Preferably using batch? Alternatively how can I run a scheduled task as the currently logged in Windows user?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this with the following code. (of course replacing MyKey)

This will apply to only signed in users registry. As I am running this code when an application is started, before it reads the registry, this works well for my case.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%A in ('reg query HKEY_USERS') do (
    set hive=%%A
    if "!hive:~11,8!"=="S-1-5-21" (
        if not "!hive:~-7!"=="Classes" (
            REG ADD !hive!\MyKey /ve /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

If you want to apply to all users whether signed in or not then this should accomplish that.

```
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
for /f %%A in ('reg query HKEY_USERS') do (
    set hive=%%A
    if not "!hive:~-7!"=="Classes" (
        REG ADD !hive!\MyKey /ve /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
    )
)
endlocal
```

Comment: Just take account that the method you're using above, is valid for hives which you cannot load, because they're already in use. A robust script would try to use one, then use the other should the first indicate failure.

Comment: I only need to apply the setting to currently logged in user, so trying to load the NTUSER.DAT file is a no go for me. It never loads if the user is already logged in. I am not really concerned about the non logged in users for this use case; however that is good to know for other situations.

Comment: I'm aware of that, Archer, and you're correct. My previous comment was meant as a clarification to others, that your solution, whilst it caters for your specific requirements, is not a robust solution for all users. I apologize if you understood it to be a criticism of your solution.

Comment: @Compo, I didn't take it as criticism at all. I can definitely see cases using the .dat file first would be wise, and then when it fails to do the "reg query" to apply to currently logged in users. I will probably use that method in the future when deploying software... I would like to understand why using the .DAT file is more robust though.

Comment: It isn't more robust, the robustness I spoke of was to allow for modifications regardless of whether the user was currently logged in or otherwise. I've certainly had instances of `reg unload` failure, which could, _if not handled appropriately_, cause corruption. A fully robust solution would probably include advice for backing up the user registry before and after any changes too.

Answer (score 0):

This first resolve SID via WMI than fill SID into the reg command. Try it..

```
for /f "delims=" %a in ('wmic useraccount where "name='%username%'" get sid') do for /f "delims=" %b in ("%a") do REG ADD HKEY_CURRENT_USER\%b /ve /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f
```

Comment: If the task is being run under the correct user profile, then the general idea seems sound. However I don't believe your current code is quite there yet. Your first loop will probably suffer from the unicode WMIC output issue and I'll assume that HKCU should be HKU too.